# MySQL Selecting and deleting whole entries

Tags: mysql, delete

I'm a total noob to mysql and i`m still trying to get my head around it. I need to select duplicate entries in a song DB and delete only those entries not in a category. I can get t to work with select. though there's an error but not with delete. Could someone help and point out my total noobness mistake?

Select Code

```
Select Songlist.ID,Artist,Title,Filename,CategoryID 
from Songlist,categorylist 
where Artist = "Lady Gaga" AND Title = "Bad Romance" AND  
(Categorylist.CategoryID <> 12)
```

Delete Code

```
Delete from * 
where Artist = "Lady Gaga" AND Title = "Bad Romance" AND  
Categorylist.CategoryID <> 12
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the error message to the question.

Comment: The first one does not throw up an error just too many returns that are duplicated. The Delete throws this back at me. SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* where Artist = "Lady Gaga" AND Title = "Bad Romance" AND  Categorylist.Cat' at line 1

Comment: Try by using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: That didnt work. I is working (Kinda) on the select statement but not on the delete. that's what is helping to really confuse me. lol.

Comment: oh I see, change `Delete from *` by `Delete from your_table_name`

Comment: I tried that also. It throws up the same problem but in a different place.   SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where Artist = "Lady Gaga" AND Title = "Bad Romance" AND (Categorylist.CategoryI' at line 2

Comment: I actually had to use two tables. hence the wildcard.  Delete from Songlist,categorylist 
where Artist = "Lady Gaga" AND Title = "Bad Romance" AND (Categorylist.CategoryID <> 12)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's DELETE syntax requires the table names involved in the DELETE.

However, I don't think the `SELECT` query is working as you want it to, either.

You have not established any connection between `Songlist` and `Categorylist`. So, it's going to give you a *cross join* - every row in `Songlist` wit the specified `Artist` and `Title`, matched with every row in `Categorylist` where `CategoryID` is not 12. If you had two matching rows in `Songlist`, and 11 matching rows in `Categorylist`, your result would be 22 rows.

Assuming you have a `CategoryID` in `Songlist`, you'd presumably want rows where the `Songlist`.`CategroyID` is not 12.

Try this:

```
Select Songlist.ID,Artist,Title,Filename,CategoryList.CategoryID 
  from Songlist
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Categorylist ON (Songlist.CategoryID = Categorylist.CategoryID)
 where Artist = "Lady Gaga"
   AND Title = "Bad Romance"
   AND (   Categorylist.CategoryID IS NULL
        OR Songlist.CategoryID <> 12
       )
;
```

This should find all records with your artist and title, where either there's no record in `Categorylist` with the `CategoryID` in `Songlist`, or where the `CategoryID` is something other than 12.

Then, the delete statement to delete those records from `Songlist` would be:

```
DELETE Songlist
  FROM Songlist
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Categorylist ON (Songlist.CategoryID = Categorylist.CategoryID)
 where Artist = "Lady Gaga"
   AND Title = "Bad Romance"
   AND (   Categorylist.CategoryID IS NULL
        OR Songlist.CategoryID <> 12
       )
;
```

Presumably, leaving only any rows with that artist and title where the `CategoryID` is 12.

NOTE: Code is, obviously, untested.

Comment: Kewl. That's probably where I am going wrong Thanks

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I now have a great understanding of where I was going wrong and have it working the way I want. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete duplicates you have to join the table with itself.

First, let's delete those duplicates where at least one of them have proper CategoryID:

```
DELETE z.* 
  FROM table AS w
  JOIN table AS z   ON z.Artist = w.Artist  -- Same artist
                   AND z.Title = w.Title    -- Same title
 WHERE w.CategoryID IS NOT NULL             -- CategoryID is set
   AND z.CategoryID IS NULL                 -- CategoryID is NOT set
;
```

Next, we have to delete duplicates, where all entries have CategoryID set:

```
DELETE z.* 
  FROM table AS w
  JOIN table AS z   ON z.Artist = w.Artist  -- Same artist
                   AND z.Title = w.Title    -- Same title
                   AND z.ID > w.ID          -- Join newer to older
 WHERE w.CategoryID IS NOT NULL             -- CategoryID is set
   AND z.CategoryID IS NOT NULL             -- CategoryID is set
;
```

But those duplicates where none of entries have CategoryID is set are still remains in the table. Let's eliminate them:

```
DELETE z.* 
  FROM table AS w
  JOIN table AS z   ON z.Artist = w.Artist  -- Same artist
                   AND z.Title = w.Title    -- Same title
                   AND z.ID > w.ID          -- Join newer to older
 WHERE w.CategoryID IS NULL                 -- CategoryID is not set
   AND z.CategoryID IS NULL                 -- CategoryID is not set
;
```

This three queries can be combined into the equivalent single one with complex `WHERE` condition with lot of `AND`s, `OR`s and braces. But for better comprehension of principle splitted queries are preferrable.

**UPDATE**

My strong advice is to replace `DELETE` by `SELECT` even on the testing base until result will be acceptable.

Comment: Thankx Kondy. I think I have it now . I am already testing with select before I test with the delete command and I have the database backed up and I have a machine with a duplicate system running. So if the worst should happen I can recover.